# People who double click everything on web pages... jQuery double click problemo

Tags: jquery

I have a link on a web page opens up a modal dialog. The first time the link is clicked  initialization code executes. Subsequent clicks do not need to do any processing. The problem here is when people double click the link the initializing code runs twice -even though I am setting a flag immediately to say that I am initialized, and if flagged don't run the init function. What should I do?

- I could unbind the click function on
  this link when clicked, but then I
  need to bind the function again when
  the dialog closes.
- I could bind to the dblclick event
  and return false?
- I could save the 'lastclicked' time
  on the element, and then check if say
  2 seconds has past before letting the
  event fire?

Comment: Can't you simply bind to the dblclick as well? I can't see why that wouldn't work.

Comment: Trouble with binding to dblclick is that if the user double clicks and I return false - the dialog will not open and the user will be left going wtf does this link not work :) I guess I could wait a couple millseconds then trigger the click function manually?

Answer (score 5):

I use [Ben Nadel's jQuery ajax wrapper](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1392-Handling-AJAX-Errors-With-jQuery.htm).  Every time you create an ajax request, you can optionally give it a name.  The ajax wrapper tracks all named requests and drops any duplicates if it's still waiting on a response from a previous request with the same name.

By putting all your ajax calls through this "pipeline", you have great centralized control over handling every call.

Comment: Hi womp - thanks for the heads up! This is something that I have struggled with a fair bit :) I will check it out!

Answer (score 0):

I made a plugin to extend the jquery ajax method and add a singleton flag, with an extra blocking flag to tell ajax to ignore all subsequent calls using this url (or key).

You call ajax normally with extra {singleton:true, blocking:true} options

When you call the same ajax twice the second call does not fire if the first call is still processing. V handy so far:

http://github.com/dougle/jQuery-Ajax-Singleton

Comment: I guess I would have to try it out :) My problem doesn't actually have anything to do with ajax - its doing a whole lot of YUI widget stuff which is very costly. So yeah wrapping the jQuery ajax stuff is fine if I was doing ajax. But in this case it is to do with a double click..